# How to set number as 10+ in BadgeDrawable in android?

Tags: android

I am using BadgeDrawable to set the number. The problem is that when i set number as 10 then it is working fine but when i set number as 10+ it is not working. Help me out i want to set number when number is less then 10 and when number is above 10 then i want to setNumber as 10+.

```
dataBind.tabLayout.getTabAt(positions)?.apply {
            orCreateBadge
            badge?.number = count
            badge?.isVisible = count != 0
            if (tabCheck == false) {
                badge?.backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.main_accent)
            } else {
                badge?.backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.gray_card)
            }
            badge?.badgeTextColor =
                resources.getColor(R.color.white)
        }
```

Comment: Why is your title asking for 7+ when your content asking for 10+?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: You probably need an `if` statement.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Can u please provide piece of code my problem is when i set 10 it is working fine but when i set 10+ it is not working

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently supported to set any text, there is an [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1217). But you can show 9+ if you set `maxCharacterCount` property to 2.